# Firebase onDataChange not called

Tags: android, firebase

I am working with Firebase for my Android app. I have successfully retrieved information in multiple places in my code using something like:

```
dbRef = new Firebase(Constants.URL_DB);
childRef = dbRef.child(Constants.KEY_CHILD);
objectRef = childRef.child(objectId); 

// Log the URL to the object.
// This has been verified. The path is good.
Log.d("DEBUG", "To String: " + objectRef.toString()); 

childRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Failure");
    }
});
```

The exact same code has been use successfully in another activity but for some reason, it doesn't work in on particular activity (onDataChange is never called, neither is onCancelled). Could it be that The Firebase sessions in other activities are conflicting with this one? I have seen problems that could be resolved with:

```
Firebase.goOnline();
Firebase.goOffline();
```

Althought I am not sure I understand what those exactly do. Maybe it is because I somehow can't access a child added by `push()` with his id?

**UPDATE:**

I successfully wrote in the database at objectRef, but `onDataChange()` is still never called.

Comment: All `Firebase` objects that you make, end up going to the same session/socket that is connected to the server. So the activities should not be interfering with each other in that respect. Instead of calling `goOffline()`/`goOnline()`, you might want to detect if the connection state changes https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found what was causing the problem. I had an empty loop because I needed the information to continue and it somehow prevented the events from the database. I had something like this in the `onCreate()`:

```
childRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Success");
        object = snapshot.getValue(MyObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("DEBUG", "Failure");
    }
});
```

And I had the loop in the `onResume()`:

```
while(object == null);
```

What I did to correct the issue was replacing the loop with:

```
if(object == null){
    // Do stuff
}
```

And I added a call to `onResume()` in `onDataChange()`

Comment: How do you access "object" from an inner class without declaring it final?

Comment: Make it an instance variable `public Object object`, or create a class with a variable of the desired type `final object = new MyObject(); object.setValue(value);`